# how to monkey patch a module inside my method

Tags: ruby

I need to include `EventMachine::Deferrable` in to `Faraday::Response`, but only if the response is created while the reactor loop is running. I know I can include a module in to a response object rather than the class, but in my case I cannot do it because of the way the context code is written.

I have a method that is invoked when the loop is running, maybe I can do it there? the below code does not work, because It simply creates a new class in the method's namespace.

```
def f
  module Faraday
    class Response
      include EventMachine::Deferrable
    end
  end
  ...
end
```

Any advice from the language experts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is how I am doing it so far. is there any better way?

```
module Faraday
  class Response
    alias :initialize_old :initialize
    def initialize env=nil
      initialize_old env
      extend EventMachine::Deferrable if EventMachine.reactor_running?
    end
  end
end
```